# How to select the records from a table1 where table1.id exists in id column of table2?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

**people**

```
name    id

man1    456
man2    123
man3    789
```

**notes**

```
content id

testing 123
hello   456
```

`SELECT DISTINCT id FROM people` is a superset of `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM notes`.

I would like to write two queries.  One which selects all the records from the table `people` for which a record in `notes` exists where the value in the id column of `notes` is equal to `people.id`.

```
name    id

man1    456
man2    123
```

The other selects all the records from the table `people` for which a record in `notes` does not exist where the value in the id column of `notes` is equal to `people.id`

```
content id

man3    789
```

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one note for the same man? I assume so since you use the word "Distinct" in both queries. Equally, is it possible to have more than one man with the same id?

Comment: Chris - it's possible to have more than one note for the same man.  It's also possible to have more than one man with the same id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM NOTES)
```

Results Man1 456 & Man2 123

```
SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM NOTES)
```

Results Man3 789

Answer (score 1):

```
--people with notes
select distinct p.id, p.name
from people p
inner join notes n on p.id = n.id

--people with no notes
select p.id, p.name
from people p
left outer join notes n on p.id = n.id
where n.id is null
```